# Cannot upload file - don't have permission to open file

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, onedrive-for-business

Some files are not uploading to a SharePoint Online document library via OneDrive for Business.

When trying to upload these particular files using the site's Upload button I get the following error message.

I am logged on to the PC as an administrator and have Full Control rights to the file.

Can someone please help?

[image: You don't have permission to open this file]

Comment: Did you check if you have permissions to the online site?

Comment: Yes, I can upload other files to the destination folder ok, either by direct upload or by OneDrive sync.

Comment: Can you try copying the file to another folder or giving it another name and upload again?

Comment: That's the answer thanks - how do I mark your post as the answer? I created new folders and moved the troublesome files to it - they instantly synced via OneDrive.

Comment: Glad it helped. Added answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try copying the file to another folder or giving it another name and upload again.